# Why this code doesn't crash during execution

Tags: c, vector, crash

I've been using C for a while and this code surprised me.

```
int main(void) {
    int array[] = {100};
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i<100; i++){
        printf("%d \n",array[i]);
    }
return 0;
}
```

When I execute this program, it doesn't crash. In the for loop, where is the number 100 put any value that you want. Beyond the array[0] position, the program outputs random numbers. I hope that someone could help me with that.

Comment: Is there any rule telling it *should* crash?

Comment: There are many, many questions like this already here on SO, the answer is always: undefined behavior permits anything to happen, including the program not crashing.

Comment: Because it didn't. A better question would be to ask why something *did* crash.

Comment: It might not crash now, but it might crash later. And in 5 hours, it might not crash again. Later, when the sun burns out, it miraculously runs on its own, and it doesn't crash, except it won't stop running. In other words, [see _Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior_](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2397984/539810)